# Using R to split a string into multiple column instead of a vector in one column

Tags: r

I want to split a column in my dataset into multiple columns based on assigned separated sign: "|".

My dataset looks like this:

```
vname<-c("x1", "x2", "x3","x4")
label<-c("1,Eng |2,Man", "1,yes|2,no|3,dont know", "1,never|2,sometimes|3,usually|4,always", "1,yes|2,No|3,dont know")
df<-data.frame(vname, label)
```

So, I want to split column: label in to multiple columns based on sign" "|". I used stringr::str_split to do that, and my code is like:

```
cd2<-df %>%
  select(vname, everything())%>%
  mutate(label=str_split(value, " \\| "))
```

However, the result returns a vector in column of label. It looks like this:

```
vname  label
x1     c("1,Eng","2,Man")
x2     c("1,yes","2,no", "3,dont know")
....
```

My question is that how to get a expected result like this:

```
vname  label1   label2      label3          label4
x1     1,Eng    2,Man
x2     1,yes    2,no         3, dont know
x3     1,never. 2,sometimes, 3,usually.     4,always
...
```

Thanks a lot for help~~~

---

```
dput(head(cd2, 10)) 
structure(list(variable = c("x2", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x13", "x14", 
"x15", "x20", "x22", NA), vname = c("consenting_language", "county", 
"respondent", "residence", "language", "int_q1", "int_q2", "int_q4", 
"int_q5", "int_q6"), label = c("Consenting Language", "County", 
"Respondent Type", "Residence", "Interview language ", "1. What was your sex at birth?", 
"2. How would you describe your current sexual orientation?", 
"4. What is the highest level of education you completed?", "5. What is your current marital status?", 
"<div class=\"rich-text-field-label\"><p>6. Is <span style=\"color: #3598db;\">regular </span>your partner currently living with you now, or does s/he stay elsewhere?</p></div>"
), value = c("1, English | 2, Kiswahili", "1, County011 | 2, County014  | 3, County002| 4, County006  | 5, County010 | 6, County008  | 7, County005  | 8, County003 | 9, County012| 10, County004 | 11, County009  | 12, County001 | 13, County015 | 14, County007 | 15, County012", 
"1, FSW | 2, MSM | 3, AGYW", "1, Urban | 2, Peri urban | 3, Rural", 
"1, English | 2, Kiswahili", "1, Male | 2, Female", "1, Homosexual/Gay | 2, Bisexual | 3, Heterosexual/Straight | 4, Transgender Male | 5, Transgender Female | 96, Other | 98, Don't Know | 99, Decline to state", 
"1,None  | 2,Nursery/kindergarten | 3,Primary | 4,Secondary | 5,Tertiary/Vocational | 6,College/University | 7,Adult education | 96,Other", 
"1, Single/Not married | 2, Married | 3, Cohabiting | 4, Divorced | 5, Separated | 6, Widowed | 7, In a relationship", 
"1, Living with You | 2, Staying Elsewhere")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the code used, it is returning a `list` (perhaps we have to make sure that there are zero or more spaces as in the example there was no space), we can `unnest_wider` to convert to new columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  select(vname, everything())%>%
  mutate(label=str_split(label, "\\s*\\|\\s*")) %>% 
  unnest_wider(where(is.list), names_sep = "")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  vname label1  label2      label3      label4  
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>   
1 x1    1,Eng   2,Man       <NA>        <NA>    
2 x2    1,yes   2,no        3,dont know <NA>    
3 x3    1,never 2,sometimes 3,usually   4,always
4 x4    1,yes   2,No        3,dont know <NA>
```

---

This maybe also done with `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
 df %>%
   separate(label, into = str_c('label', 
   seq_len(max(str_count(.$label, fixed("|"))) + 1)), 
      sep = "\\|", fill = "right")
```

-output

```
 vname  label1      label2      label3   label4
1    x1  1,Eng        2,Man        <NA>     <NA>
2    x2   1,yes        2,no 3,dont know     <NA>
3    x3 1,never 2,sometimes   3,usually 4,always
4    x4   1,yes        2,No 3,dont know     <NA>
```

---

Or using the OP's data 'cd2' - added the case for spaces before and after the `|`

```
cd2new <- cd2 %>% 
   separate(value, into = str_c('value', 
   seq_len(max(str_count(.$value, fixed("|"))) + 1)), 
      sep = "\\s*\\|\\s*", fill = "right")
```

-output

```
> head(cd2new, 2)
  variable               vname               label       value1       value2       value3       value4       value5
1       x2 consenting_language Consenting Language   1, English 2, Kiswahili         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>
2       x8              county              County 1, County011 2, County014 3, County002 4, County006 5, County010
        value6       value7       value8       value9       value10       value11       value12       value13
1         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>
2 6, County008 7, County005 8, County003 9, County012 10, County004 11, County009 12, County001 13, County015
        value14       value15
1          <NA>          <NA>
2 14, County007 15, County012
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun, may I ask why my R tells me that could not find function"where" after I installed all 3 of them? Is the "where" masked by other package? Is it from dplyr package? Thanks a lot~~~!

Comment: `where` is from `tidyselect` which the dplyr uses.  Some packages are automaticlaly installed as dependency when you install dplyr.  I am guessing that you may have an older version of packages i.e. I used `packageVersion('tidyselect')#
[1] ‘1.1.2’
> packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.9’`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I am still figuring how to solve the version issue. For the second method, the R keeps warning me that "Error in stri_count_fixed(string, pattern, opts_fixed = opts(pattern)) : object 'value' not found". I copied your template and only changed the variable name from label to value. Could you help to see where is  wrong? Thanks~~~

Comment: @Rstudyer `value` not found is not clear as there is no column name in the example that is `value`.  I used `packageVersion('stringr')#
[1] ‘1.4.0’`

Comment: @Rstudyer if the label is `value`, then can you show your code?

Comment: Thanks @akrun, here is my code:  cd3<-cd2%>%
  separate(label, into = str_c('value', seq_len(max(str_count(value, fixed("|"))) + 1)), sep = "\\|", fill = "right"). Here cd2 is equal to df in example, and "value" is equal to "label" in example.

Comment: @Rstudyer shouldn't `separate(label` be `separate(value` as value is the coliumn name and  not label in cd2

Comment: right right. Thanks for pointing it out... I corrected that and the warning still exists...

Comment: @Rstudyer is it a warning or error?  Can you `dput` the example to check i.e. `dput(head(cd2, 10))`

Comment: it is an error..., Yeah, I will try to duplicate the dataset and check, thanks a lot~~~:)

Comment: @Rstudyer use `dput` so that i get the structure correctly

Comment: hi @akrun, I run it, but comment has words limit, I cannot show the result here, should I put it somewhere so you could see that? Thanks a lot~~:) It loos like this: structure(list(variable = c("x2", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x13", "x14", 
"x15", "x20", "x22", NA), vname = c("consenting_language", "county", 
"respondent", "residence", "language", "int_q1", "int_q2", "int_q4", 
"int_q5", "int_q6"), label = c("Consenting Language", "County", 
"Respondent Type", "Residence", "Interview language ", "1. What was your sex at birth?",

Comment: @Rstudyer the structure needs to be complete or else I can't test it.  Could you update your post with the dput(head(cd2))`

Comment: Thanks so much, @akrun, I just updated my post. Thanks for taking your time to help~~:)

Comment: @Rstudyer there was a typo as I didn't notice that 'label' was created as vector.  You need `cd2 %>%   separate(value, into = str_c('value', 
   seq_len(max(str_count(.$value, fixed("|"))) + 1)), 
      sep = "\\s*\\|\\s*", fill = "right")`

Comment: It works perfectly~~~!!! Thanks so much for your help~~!@akrun~~

Answer (score 3):

you can do this simply by using `separate()` from {tidyr}

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  separate(value, sep = "\\s*\\|\\s*", 
           into = paste0("value", seq(str_count(.$value, "\\s*\\|\\s*"))))
```

Comment: Thanks @shafee, it is helpful~~! The challenge is the label in my real dataset can be split from 1 to n, so it is hard to set "1:4".